# select and count nested elements with regex expression

Tags: regex, xpath

I have an XML file like this:

```
<apps>
    <mobile-app>
    </mobile-app>
    <mobile-app>
    </mobile-app>
    <web-app>
    </web-app>
    <xpto>
    </xpto>
</apps>
```

and I want to count how many `*-apps` I have in it, something like `count(//apps/"<(.*)-app>")`.

Already tried to search here but it is difficult as many questions have the xpath expression related with functions of some programming language, which is something I want to avoid here.

Comment: Which version of XPath? If you really expect to use regular expressions you need to use XPath 2 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 or later to solve that with regular expression matching you could use `count(apps/*[matches(local-name(), '-app$')])`. However, the check that the end of the name is `-app` it would suffice to use `ends-with(local-name(), '-app')`.